# How to use tf.nn.raw_rnn function in Tensorflow?

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning

I am trying to implement LSTM based network where after hidden state computation we also apply linear + sigmoid transformation at each time step. I have found the [official documentation](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/nn/raw_rnn) and [a nice article](https://hanxiao.github.io/2017/08/16/Why-I-use-raw-rnn-Instead-of-dynamic-rnn-in-Tensorflow-So-Should-You-0/) that describe `tf.nn.raw_rnn` function suitable for this task however I struggle to understand why it does not work in my particular case.

#### Input description

So, let our input to LSTM be a minibatch of size `[num_steps x batch_size x size]`, concretely `[5, 32, 100]`. Let LSTM have 200 hidden units. Then the output of the LSTM is `[5, 32, 200]` tensor which we can later use for loss computation. I assume the input `[5, 32, 100]` tensor is first unstacked into an array of `[32, 100]` tensors and then stacked back if we use `tf.nn.dynamic_rnn` with `time_major=True` in Tensorflow:

```
                                      tf.nn.dynamic_rnn(LSTM)
                   LSTM t=0    LSTM t=1   LSTM t=2   LSTM t=3   LSTM t=4  
[5, 32, 100] -->   [[32, 100], [32, 100], [32, 100], [32, 100], [32, 100]] --> [5, 32, 200]
```

#### Hidden state model

In addition after each LSTM cell I need to perform linear + sigmoid transformation to squash each `[32, 200]` tensor into `[32, 1]` for example. Our `tf.nn.dynamic_rnn` won't work for that since it only accepts cells. We need to use `tf.nn.raw_rnn` API. So, here is my try:

```
def _get_raw_rnn_graph(self, inputs):
    time = tf.constant(0, dtype=tf.int32)
    _inputs_ta = tf.TensorArray(dtype=tf.float32, size=5)
    # our [5, 32, 100] tensor becomes [[32, 100], [32, 100], ...]
    _inputs_ta = _inputs_ta.unstack(inputs)  

    # create simple LSTM cell
    cell = tf.contrib.rnn.LSTMCell(config.hidden_size)

    # create loop_fn for raw_rnn
    def loop_fn(time, cell_output, cell_state, loop_state):
        emit_output = cell_output  # == None if time = 0

        if cell_output is None:  # time = 0
            next_cell_state = cell.zero_state(32, tf.float32)
            self._initial_state = next_cell_state
        else:
            next_cell_state = cell_state

        elements_finished = (time >= 32)
        finished = tf.reduce_all(elements_finished)
        next_input = tf.cond(finished,
                             lambda: tf.zeros([32, config.input_size], dtype=tf.float32),                                                   
                             lambda: _inputs_ta.read(time))

        # apply linear + sig transform here
        next_input = self._linear_transform(next_input, activation=tf.sigmoid)

        next_loop_state = None
        return (elements_finished, next_input, next_cell_state, emit_output, next_loop_state)

    outputs_ta, final_state, _ = tf.nn.raw_rnn(cell, loop_fn)
    outputs = outputs_ta.stack()
    return outputs, final_state
```

This unfortunately does not work. The `loop_fn` iterates only two times instead of `num_steps` times as I expected and its output is `Tensor("Train/Model/TensorArrayStack/TensorArrayGatherV3:0", shape=(?, 32, 200), dtype=float32)` not `[5, 32, 1]` as we intended. What am I missing here?